# Is there a way to estimate the shape or curvature of a function given some data points?

Tags: functions, curves, curvature, parameter-estimation

I have a series of measurements (data points), we can call them Ys for now, and two input variables m and n, such that f(m,n) = Y. Is there an easy way to compute the shape or curvature for function f that maps m,n into Ys - i.e., determining whether the function is polynomial or something else? Thanks!

Comment: If all you have is a finite number of points, then no. There is always a polynomial that passes through all of your points. In fact, there are infinitely many such polynomials. You can get a lower limit on the degree of polynomials matching your function, but that is the best you can do without knowing something more about the function than just some points on it.

Comment: I can generate more data points if necessary. How would I go about determining the lower limit that you mentioned?